# "pure" explanation of Reed-Solomon?

Tags: coding-theory

I encountered two applications of RS codes - one in group testing, and another time someone said that a solution to an [interview question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492302/easy-interview-question-got-harder-given-numbers-1-100-find-the-missing-numbe) was using it. But when I search for explanations, it's all about the cracks in the CD disks and such. Is there a good source that puts the math first?

Comment: You can try Wikipedia, as well as any monograph or lecture notes on coding theory from a mathematical perspective, for example [this recent monograph](https://cse.buffalo.edu/faculty/atri/courses/coding-theory/book/).

Answer (score 1):

Jon Hall's coding theory notes, available online [here](https://users.math.msu.edu/users/halljo/classes/codenotes/coding-notes.html) are quite good. See Chapter 5.

In addition, see Blahut's text *Algebraic Codes for Data Transmission* where more focus on decoding algorithms is present.